# Rmarkdown not building model equation to word

Tags: r, r-markdown

This is my code for linear model

```
model = lm(UCBRpk~ pksa + dist)
summary(model)
```

```
equatiomatic::extract_eq(model,wrap = TRUE)
```

```
equatiomatic::extract_eq(model, wrap = TRUE,use_coefs = TRUE)
```

I got the equation when knitting to **html** and **pdf**, but unable in **word**

This is the usual error message each time I knit to **word**:

```
unexpected "&"
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '
  \begin{aligned}
  \operatorname{\widehat{SCBRcp}} &= 43.34 + 3.53(\operatorname{cpa}_{\operatorname{10\%}}) + 2.68(\operatorname{cpa}_{\operatorname{2\%}}) + 4.67(\operatorname{cpa}_{\operatorname{4\%}})\ + \\
  &\quad 8.9(\operatorname{cpa}_{\operatorname{6\%}}) + 6.24(\operatorname{cpa}_{\operatorname{8\%}}) + 3.15(\operatorname{dist}_{\operatorname{A2}}) - 1.81(\operatorname{dist}_{\operatorname{A3}})
  \end{aligned}
  ', rendering as TeX:
  d}
```

Comment: It is not an error, but a warning

Answer (score 4):

#### tldr;

Seems like a bug with `equatiomatic`; I recommend opening an issue.

---

The issue is with the `\operatorname` calls in the LaTeX code produced by `equatiomatic`. I don't know whether the culprit is MathJax (since the expression itself is valid LaTeX) but a more minimal example reproducing your issue is as follows:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{\widehat{x}} &= a + b\ + \\
 &\quad c + d
\end{aligned}
$$
```

which upon knitting produces the following warning

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '
  \begin{aligned}
  \operatorname{\widehat{x}} &= a + b\ + \\
   &\quad c + d
  \end{aligned}
  ', rendering as TeX:
  ligned}
                     ^
  unexpected "&"
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
```

I am not familiar with `equatiomatic` but in my (LaTeX) opinion, the translation of those equations into LaTeX should use `\mathrm` rather than `\operatorname` (see e.g. [What's the difference between \mathrm and \operatorname?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname/48463) for a discussion and examples on how these two differ; amongst other things, `\operatorname` treats punctuation symbols like text whereas `\mathrm` treats them as math symbols. Perhaps -- and I'm 100% speculating here -- that's the reason why the `equatiomatic` devs decided to use `\operatorname` rather than `\mathrm`).

If I replace all `\operatorname` calls with `\mathrm` your example expression compiles fine.

```r
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{\widehat{SCBRcp}} &= 43.34 + 3.53(\mathrm{cpa}_{\mathrm{10\%}}) + 2.68(\mathrm{cpa}_{\mathrm{2\%}}) + 4.67(\mathrm{cpa}_{\mathrm{4\%}})\ + \\
  &\quad 8.9(\mathrm{cpa}_{\mathrm{6\%}}) + 6.24(\mathrm{cpa}_{\mathrm{8\%}}) + 3.15(\mathrm{dist}_{\mathrm{A2}}) - 1.81(\mathrm{dist}_{\mathrm{A3}})
  \end{aligned}
$$
```

[image]

So long story short, what can you do? Other than manually editing the output of `equatiomatic` I recommend opening an issue on the [`equatiomatic` GH site](https://github.com/datalorax/equatiomatic), and cross-linking to this post on Stack Overflow.